# Check if all elements of a cv::mat are positive or equal to 0

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a matrix  `cv::mat A` . 
Is there an easy way to check if all elements of this matrix are positive or equal to 0, and return a True boolean if this condition is true?

Comment: Why not just find the minimum and see if it is non-negative?

Comment: @MarkSetchell And whats the difference ? You still have to go through the whole Matrix.

Comment: The difference is that the built-in functions are **heavily** optimised for SIMD operation.

Answer (score 2):

@francesco answer is nice in terms of C++, but not really effective nor functional tho.

More effective method is using OpenCV built-in operation called [checkRange()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#checkrange), it also provides position of first invalid element and support for multi-channel array.

Example usage:

```
cv::Point *pos;
bool is_ok = cv::checkRange( A, pos, 0, DBL_MAX );
```

---

As @MarkSetchell suggested in comments, you might also find minimum value in matrix and see if it is non-negative. There is one OpenCV operation on array called `minMaxLoc()` which unfortunately doesn't work with multi-channel arrays, so you would have to reinterper whole array as single channel, first.

```
double min;
cv::minMaxLoc( A.reshape(1), &min );
```

---

To make francescos solution work, you have to specify `cv::Mat` type to iterators, eg. for `CV_8U` type of matrix

```
bool is_all_positive = (std::find_if(m.begin<uchar>(), m.end<uchar>(),
     [](auto x) { return (x < 0); }) == m.end<uchar>());
```

As I previously said, this is not effective approach and would be (in my opinion) more useable than `checkRange()` just in case we would like to compare values of specific channels - e.g. checking only for values of blue color in BGR image

```
bool is_all_positive = (std::find_if(m.begin<cv::Vec3b>(), m.end<cv::Vec3b>(),
     [](auto x) { return (x[0] < 0); }) == m.end<cv::Vec3b>());
```

Answer (score 1):

To have an efficient method, rather than using procedures that iterate over all elements of the matrix, you should use a method that stops as soon as a condition is found. You can use `std::find_if`

```
#include <algorithm>

bool is_all_positive = (std::find_if(A.begin(), A.end(),
    [](auto x) { return (x < 0); }) == A.end());
```

Comment: You should set the template of `A` when using begin or end, e.g. `A.begin<uchar>()`.